# java2-runtime virtual package not considered installed by dpkg/apt-get

Tags: apt, java, dpkg

Did a fresh install of Quetzal Server, installed all updates. Installed `default-jre-headless` which pulled in OpenJDK 7 JRE without any X11-related packages. So far so good.

Now I try to install http://nectar-downloads.cloudbees.com/jenkins-enterprise/1.466/debian/binary/jenkins_1.466.2.1_all.deb (via `apt-get` after adding a software source and `apt-get update`) whose header according to `apt-cache show jenkins` says

```
Depends: daemon, adduser, psmisc, java2-runtime
```

But this proposes to install OpenJDK 6—with GUI!

```
$ apt-get -s install jenkins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fontconfig hicolor-icon-theme icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm
  icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common jenkins libasound2 libasyncns0
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libcairo2 libdatrie1 libflac8 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common
  libgif4 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libjasper1 libjbig0
  libjson0 libogg0 libpango1.0-0 libpixman-1-0 libpulse0 libsndfile1
  libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libxcb-render0
  libxcb-shm0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6
  libxinerama1 libxml2 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxtst6 openjdk-6-jre
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib sgml-base shared-mime-info
  ttf-dejavu-extra x11-common xml-core
```

Why is `apt-get` not happy with the Java 7 runtime I already installed and which provides this virtual package?

```
$ grep-available -F Provides -s Package java2-runtime
Package: openjdk-7-jre-headless
Package: default-jre-headless
```

Even if I manually install the one missing dependency, `daemon`, there appears to be no way to force `apt-get install jenkins` to not try to pull in new Java dependencies.

I also tried downloading the `*.deb` and using `dpkg -i` to install it manually. But this also fails:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jenkins:
 jenkins depends on java2-runtime; however:
  Package java2-runtime is not installed.
```

(Note: I am deliberately not here testing the `jenkins` package in Universe, which has a different dependency list…which seems to behave even worse.)

Answer (score 1):

Not reproducible in Raring with a 1.509.x build after installing `default-jdk`. Not sure whether the difference is installing the full JDK; or a package metadata difference in the JDK for Raring; or a package metadata difference in Jenkins (I do not think so); or a bug fix to apt-get in Raring.